# How to create a message in a storage queue using an Azure Logic App and the SQL Connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a message in a Storage Queue using Azure Logic Apps and I can't for the life of me work out how to do it.  I have managed to trigger the Logic App using the `When an item is modified (V2)` trigger and that works great.

I have successfully created a message in my storage queue using the `Azure Queues -> Put a message on a queue` action, dead easy!

However the message is simply each data column in sequence with no structure e.g.

```
1Andy Was Ere!�������ï¿½1
```

What I wish to do is add a step where the Logic App takes the data extracted from the SQL database and formats it into a JSON object and then creates the message in the storage queue so I end up with e.g.

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Data": "Andy Was Ere!",
    "RowVersion": "�������ï¿½",
    "Status": 1
}
```

I was hoping there would be a data adaptor that would allow me to convert the input fields from my SQL database into a JSON representation, I'm sure this is very simple once you know how however I can find no practical example of this being done??

Answer (score 1):

As per usual straight after posting the question I come up with a solution, it might not be the best one so I would be happy to hear any additional feedback.

**Step 1**
Create your `SQL Server -> When an item is modified (V2)` trigger.

**Step 2**
Add an `Execute Javascript Code` action and add your JSON object transformation code e.g.

```
return {
    "id": workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.Id,
    "myData": workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.MyData,
    "status": workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.Status
}
```

**Step 3**
Add a `Data -> Compose` action  that accepts the input from the JS action.

**Step 4**
Add a Azure Queues -> Put a message on a queue action with the message being the Output from the Compose action above

Something else I acquired the answer for whilst implementing this test is, if I have multiple records triggered then a single trigger is raised for each change.

Comment: Do you know how to get only the columns that actually have been updated and not the entire row from a SQL table?

Comment: Sorry no I gave up on the whole thing due to the fact the whole process operates on a polling methodology which defeated the object of what I was trying to do.